# Chrome blurred text with video element

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, blurry

I'm developing a web app and in one of my pages I have a video element that shows the user's webcam video.

I noticed the page was a little blurry and then I was messing with the developer tools and deleted the video element and now the page was really sharp.

Images:
[image: Blurred page]

[image: Not blurred]

The first image is the slightly blurred page with the video element and the second one is the sharp one without video element.

The page looks fine on Firefox but not on Chrome.

Chrome version: 47.0.2526.106 m

Comment: did you every find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No solution found so far. Some Chrome updates came but the problem persists